# Is this has anything to do with Riesz representation?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis, calculus-of-variations

The Riesz representation is very useful in study BV space. There is a lot of version of it and one of the good one can be found in [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1482242389) book, page 49.

Here I come up with a question which has similar assumption as Riesz representation but different in some way, and I am wondering that could I make some conclusion similar to Riesz representation.

Suppose $\mu\in\mathcal M(I)$ where $I\subset \mathbb R^1$ is open interval and $\mathcal M(I)$ denotes all fnite Rodan measures. Assume 
$$
\sup\left\{\int_I \phi'\,d\mu, \,\phi\in C_c^\infty(I),\,\|\phi\|_{L^{\infty}(I)}\leq1,\,\|\phi'\|_{L^\infty}\leq 1\right\}<\infty \tag 2
$$
Then I am wondering that can I have some similar result compare to Riesz representation? Since in the integration is $\phi'$ but not $\phi$ and the constraint is on $W^{1,\infty}$ norm and it is much stronger then the $L^\infty$ norm in usual Riesz representation, I am not expecting I will have same result as in Riesz. But would it be possible to conclude something similar to integration by parts formula? i.e., to have another Radon measure $\nu$ such that 
$$
\int_I\phi'\,d\mu = -\int_I\phi\,d\nu\tag 1
$$
Any help is really welcome!

Comment: What form of Sobolev norm are you using, i. e. how are the sup-norm of the function and it's derivative combined?

Comment: @Dirk Let me just put $\|\phi\|_{L^\infty}\leq 1$ and $\|\phi'\|_{L^\infty}\leq 1$. This question actually come from the study of $TGV^2$ space.

Comment: One more thing: Your functional is not linear but only positively homogeneous, so what kind of result do you expect?

Comment: @Dirk not linear? The functional $L(\phi):=\int_I\phi'd\mu$ is linear right? Or am I make some trivial mistake here... I think the TGV definition is linear. What I expect is a kind of relation as I stated in equation $(1)$ above.

Comment: This defines a distribution ("generalized function") that is the derivative of the measure $\mu$ (which is itself a distribution.

Comment: @DeaneYang So the equation $(1)$ I wrote above is true? I only have $\nu\in \mathcal M(I)$ right? Not any more regularity? Could you please provide more reference of this? Thank you!

Comment: $\nu$ is *not* a measure. It is a distribution (as defined by Laurent Schwartz). See, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)

Comment: To be more precise, a distribution is a continuous linear functional on, say, $C^\infty_c(I)$ with respect to the Frechet topology. The derivative of a distribution is a distribution. In this example, the distributions $\alpha: \phi \rightarrow \int \phi\,d\mu$ and $\beta: \phi\rightarrow \int \phi'\,d\mu$ satisfy $\beta' = -\alpha$, where the operator $\beta \mapsto \beta'$ is commonly known as weak differentiation and is defined using integration by parts, as you have described.

Comment: @DeaneYang I see. But I still confused about one thing. In order to say the operator $\beta\to\beta'$ exists, do I need to use condition $(2)$? One more thing is, from your comment, could I understand that you mean $(1)$ is not true and such $\nu$ does not exist, as a measure?

Comment: @DeaneYang Also, here is the whole story of my question... http://mathoverflow.net/questions/211776/question-about-tgv2-space

Comment: Nope, not linear since flipping the sign of my won't flip the sign of the value.

Comment: Condition (2) is needed to show that the operator $\beta \mapsto \beta'$ is continuous in the Frechet topology of the space of distributions. And, yes, $\nu$ is in general not a measure. It is something weaker than that. Condition (1) holds, if interpreted appropriately. Since $\nu$ is not a measure, it cannot hold since it isn't even well-defined.